# Global Variable issue Always zero

Tags: c#

This is my code :

```
public void calculQuita(QUITA quita, decimal total)
{ ../
    total = commission; //Affection Value of commission to Total , like this i can use it out side of my void

}

public void CalculCom(int id)
{
    ...
    decimal totalCOM = 0;
    foreach (QUITA quita in quitaList)
    {
        decimal total = 0;
        calculQuita(quita,total);
        totalCOM += total;
    }
   ....
}
```

The problem after Runing my Program `TotalCom` is always ZERO. what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: You are setting it to zero. And then adding zero. Over and over again. Why wouldn't it be zero?

Comment: As @AntP mentioned, you are adding 0 (the value of "total") to "totalCOM". The call to "calculQuita(quita,total)" does not modify "total". Perhaps you want to change the function to do something like "total = calculQuita(quita,total)", or something.

Comment: @AntP Try to read code next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calculQuita` method doesn't change the value of `total` it changes the value of the parameter (total) which is the copy of your variable `total`, you need to pass it as a `ref` parameter if you want to change it's value:

```
public void calculQuita(QUITA quita, ref decimal total)
{ ../
    total = commission; 

}

public void CalculCom(int id)
{
    ...
    decimal totalCOM = 0;
    foreach (QUITA quita in quitaList)
    {
        decimal total = 0;
        calculQuita(quita,ref total);
        totalCOM += total;
    }
   ....
}
```

**Further reading**

- [ref Keyword (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Comment: This will "work," but is a pretty terrible thing to suggest to a novice programmer. Very pretty terrible. Here comes an entire programming career of passing everything by reference all the time and never understanding why.

Comment: @AntP at least I'm giving a solution and point him to the documentation to understand **why** instead of posting useless comments

Comment: I promise you he doesn't understand why. Frankly it's better to be unhelpful than to be anti-helpful.

Comment: @AntP - Chlebta is clearly a beginner programmer asking a specific question. I'm sure he will learn the value of return statements soon enough in his own time. Saying something like "Here comes an entire programming career of..." is both overly extreme and implying that you can predict another person's future. Chill out dude.

Comment: @AntP It's true I'm beginners but I know what means using ref and how it work's.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I've come across (professional) programmers who have spent their entire programming careers passing everything by reference and have no concept of the implications or that there is even an alternative - it's really not that wild a notion. But really, I was using hyperbole. The point being that demonstrating a better approach is favourable to simply making a poor approach work; especially in the case of beginners who will develop habits without the knowledge to properly evaluate them.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `calculQuita` is actually changing a *copy* of total. If you want it to change the value that gets passed in, you must add the `ref` keyword.

```
public void calculQuita(QUITA quita, ref decimal total)
{ ../
    total = commission; //Affection Value of commission to Total , like this i can use it out side of my void

}


public void CalculCom(int id)
{
    ...
    decimal totalCOM = 0;
    foreach (QUITA quita in quitaList)
    {
        decimal total = 0;
        calculQuita(quita, ref total);
        totalCOM += total;
    }
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing the `total` by reference as in the other answers. `ref` should only ever be used when you absolutely know what you're doing. The proper approach is to return the value of `commission` from the `calculQuita` method and use it as appropriate.

```
public decimal calculQuita(QUITA quita)
{
    var total = 0d;
    // ...
    return commission; 
}

public void CalculCom(int id)
{
    ...
    decimal totalCOM = 0;
    foreach (QUITA quita in quitaList)
    {
        totalCOM += calculQuita(quita);
    }
   ....
}
```

I've removed the `total` parameter from `calculQuita` as it doesn't appear necessary - you can still pass it in if it ever starts at a value other than zero.

Comment: Regardless of downvotes (presumably based on spite), this is the proper approach to solving this problem where the others abuse the `ref` keyword.

Comment: I havn't use return because I got some other Variable thier value gona be changed.

Comment: @Chlebta If there are other factors of your code that will affect the answer, they should have been included in your question. I'm not a mindreader.

Comment: Also, if doing this causes side-effects, that is indicative of other flaws in your code, not an issue with the approach in the answer. A method to calculate commission should do just that. You should elaborate on what side-effects you think this will have.